# UPDATE with IF/ELSE

Tags: sql-server

I want to achieve the following:

```
UPDATE users 
    IF defaultView = @newDefault 
    THEN SET defaultView = NULL
    ELSE SET defaultView = @newDefault 
WHERE id = @userid
```

Unlike you, SQL server does not understand what I want to achieve.

So, how would I do this - syntactically correct - in one SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
defaultView  =
CASE 
    WHEN defaultView = @newDefault 
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE @newDefault  
END
WHERE id = @userid
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

```
UPDATE users 
SET defaultView = NULLIF(@newDefault , defaultView)
WHERE id = @userid
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a case statement rather than an IF ELSE

```
   UPDATE users
   set defaultview = 
           CASE
           WHEN defaultview = @newDefault
           THEN NULL
           ELSE @newDefault
           END
  WHERE id = @userid
```